# What exactly does line:270 open (M, "|-") || exec("/usr/lib/sendmail","-f",$from,$to) do in smokeping 2.6.11

Tags: perl

line 269@smokeping-2.6.11/lib/Somkeping.pm from http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/pub/smokeping-2.6.11.tar.gz shown below,

```
} elsif ($cfg->{General}{sendmail} or -x "/usr/lib/sendmail"){
        open (M, "|-") || exec (($cfg->{General}{sendmail} || "/usr/lib/sendmail"),"-f",$from,$to);
        print M $body;
        close M;
```

I am really wondering why not use open instead?

```
open (M,"| /usr/lib/sendmail -f $from $to");
```

What are pros & cons with both method, and when to using them?

I have read http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html already, but I still do not understanding what's actually going on inside this piece of code.

Thanks in advance.

PS. I'm asking open (M, "|-") || exec("/bin/program") , I do not need the explanation of cfg sendmail path/hardcode sendmail path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the solution you suggest:

```
open(M, "| $sendmail -f $from $to");
```

Switching to this would not be a good idea. It introduces bugs that did not exist in the original due to improper interpolation. Imagine if `$sendmail` contained a space. Imagine if `$to` was `Foo Bar <foobar@example.com>`. To build the shell command properly, you'd have to use

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
open(M, "|" . shell_quote($sendmail, "-f", $from, $to));
```

or

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
open(M, "|-", shell_quote($sendmail, "-f", $from, $to));
```

I think they wanted to avoid having to depend on String::ShellQuote, and they wanted to avoid the work of writing the equivalent code.

---

However, there is something better they could have used. They could simply have used the following:

```
open(M, "|-", $sendmail, "-f", $from, $to);
```

This does not use a shell. Aside from being simpler and more efficient, this saves us from having to build a shell command. It launches `sendmail` directly (without going through a shell), and passed the list of arguments to it as-is.

So to answer your question, they use what they used because your version is buggy, and either they didn't know about this version or they wanted compatibility with version of Perl that from before 2000 when this was introduced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too. Your answer also teach me a lot.

Comment: I think the answer you picked is poorly written and doesn't even answer your question. It hints at Windows portability, but that's nonsense.

Comment: After reviewing both answer again, I agreed that your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

The answers depend considering the question is a little bit vague.

a) if you are asking why the author wrote `open (M, "|-") || exec("bin")` instead of `open (M, | bin)`

The reason might be they cannot make sure where is the executable binary located, meanwhile the alternative will make more duplicate codes.

i.e.

```
open (M, "|-") || exec("bin1" || "bin2")
```

versus

```
open (M, "| bin1") or open(M, "| bin2")
```

Not to mention that there are some extra parameters for the program.

b) if you are asking the differences between `open(M, "|-") || exec("bin")` and `open(M, "| bin")`

AFAIK, there's no differences between them according to the perl's document.

And I would like to add that it would be better if the the focus of this question can be clarified by the author.

Comment: It's b that I was asking.